# Fluent NHibernate: "collection is not associated with any session"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm getting this error message:

```
collection is not associated with any session
```

When I execute this code:

```
var post = Posts.Query().First(p => p.Id == id);
```

id is passed on via the controller.

My mappings look like this:

```
public PostMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.Title);
    Map(x => x.UserId);
    Map(x => x.DateTime);
    Map(x => x.Content);
    Map(x => x.CategoryId, "category");
    Map(x => x.ReplyTo, "reply_to");
    References(x => x.User, "userid").ReadOnly().Not.LazyLoad();
    References(x => x.Category, "category").ReadOnly().Not.LazyLoad();
    HasMany(x => x.Replies).KeyColumn("reply_to").ReadOnly().Not.LazyLoad();
    Table("posts");
}
public CategoryMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.Name);
    Map(x => x.ParentId, "parent");
    Map(x => x.SubCategory, "subcategory");
    HasMany(x => x.Posts).KeyColumn("category").ReadOnly().Not.LazyLoad();
    HasMany(x => x.Categories).KeyColumn("parent").ReadOnly().Not.LazyLoad();
    Table("categories");
}
public UserMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.Username).Not.Nullable();
    Map(x => x.Password).Not.Nullable();
    Map(x => x.Email).Not.Nullable();         
    Map(x => x.Firstname);
    Map(x => x.Surname);
    Map(x => x.Salt);
    Map(x => x.Privilege);
    HasMany(x => x.Messages).KeyColumn("msg_to_userid").ReadOnly().Not.LazyLoad();
    HasMany(x => x.SentMessages).KeyColumn("msg_from_userid").ReadOnly().Not.LazyLoad();
    Table("users");
}
```

And Query() is a method that returns an IQueryable()

Does anyone know what the issue might be?

**Edit**
This is really weird. If a user is logged in, it doesn't work at all. **BUT** if a user is not logged in, it works every other time. If I get the exception, continue and refresh again it works, then if I refresh again it doesn't work. I'm fairly sure it has something to do with the session and mapping.

My session is set up like this in BaseController

```
protected HttpSessionState SessionState
{
    get { return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session; }
}
    protected User User
    {
        get
        {
            if (_user != null)
                return _user;
            if (SessionState["User"] == null)
                return null;
            return (_user = Users.Get((int)SessionState["User"]));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected User User
    {
        get
        {
            if (_user != null)
                return _user;
```

Problem is with above statement, where you are storing the user in a variable in the controller which might exist beyond the lifespan of the session. You should NEVER store entities in such variables, rather store primary key and fetch the entity whenever you need it / or store a DTO.

Comment: The whole point of hibernate is that it allows you to map object graphs to their udnerlying representation - if you don't do that then you may as well nto use hibernate.

Comment: How does this answer contradic with that?